# 2 column layout with "show/hide" function, text bleeds into second column.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new here and by no means a professional web developer, so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to create a two column layout, each with 'show/hide' function to display an abstract. However when I click "show" the text bleeds into the next column. My code looks like this:

```
 <div id="content" class="clearfix" style="margin:0px auto; width:70%">
    <h2>Session 1</h2>
      <div id="column1" style="float:left; margin:0; width:50%;"><span class="content">
        <p><strong><span lang="EN-US" xml:lang="EN-US">Panel 2A:</span></strong><span lang="EN-US" xml:lang="EN-US"> <strong><em>Visual arts</em></strong></span></p>
        <p><b>Sp. 1 NAME</b> - <br />
          &lsquo;PAPER NAME&rsquo;<br />
          <a href="#" id="show_abstract_1" onClick="InsertContent('abstract_1');InsertContent('hide_abstract_1');RemoveContent('show_abstract_1');return false;">view abstract</a><a href="#" id="hide_abstract_1" onClick="RemoveContent('abstract_1');InsertContent('show_abstract_1');RemoveContent('hide_abstract_1');return false;" style="display:none;">hide abstract</a>
          <span id="abstract_1" style="color:#312B85;display:none;"><br />TESTTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest</span></p>
    </div>

<div id="column3" style="float:left; margin:0;width:50%"><span class="content">
  <p><strong><span lang="EN-US" xml:lang="EN-US">Panel 2B:</span></strong><span lang="EN-US" xml:lang="EN-US"> <strong><em>Architecture and applied arts</em></strong></span></p>
  <p align="left"><strong>Sp. 5 NAME</strong><br />
    &lsquo;PAPER NAME&rsquo;<br />
    <a href="#" id="show_abstract_2" onClick="InsertContent('abstract_2');InsertContent('hide_abstract_2');RemoveContent('show_abstract_2');return false;">view abstract</a><a href="#" id="hide_abstract_2" onClick="RemoveContent('abstract_2');InsertContent('show_abstract_2');RemoveContent('hide_abstract_2');return false;" style="display:none;">hide abstract</a>
    <span id="abstract_2" style="color:#312B85;display:none;"><br />
   TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest</span></p>
</div>
```

This code is [jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/BUk9H/)

Any help advice would be appreaciated. Have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Provide a working example on jsfiddle.net or something please.

Comment: Change your text from TestTestTest... to something with spaces in it. Or use some CSS to break the long words to multiple lines: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle demo of your issue for us to debug?  You may find your problem on your own as you do so.

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem is without seeing the code for your `InsertContent` function. A wild guess: try putting the "column3" div before the "content" div. I think maybe you want "column3" to be floated to the left of "content", but floated elements have to come before non-floated elements in the HTML.

Comment: RobH thank you.. The problem was with the TESTTESTTEST text. I knew I would be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text : TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest  is out of common sense. You should consider a 'lorem ipsum' test text witch has spaces to break.

For your context, you can try 'overflow:hidden' and/or  'text-overflow:ellipsis'

Comment: In case you're not familiar with "lorem ipsum," it's just dummy text; see http://www.lipsum.com/

Comment: Yes someone suggested this and it has worked. I am familiar with this, just lazily comied and pasted test, didn't think it would matter, but obviously I was wrong. Thanks to all of you who have commented and saved me a headache!

Comment: -1 for the ''just lazily comied and pasted test, didn't think it would matter''  ;)